Discrepancies in MODIS Active Fire Data: Points Less than1 km Apart despite 1 km Resolution
I am using MODIS active fire point data, monitoring the fire activity. According to the data description, the fire points are recorded at the center of the grid, so theoretically, the closest distance between two fire points should be around 1 km regardless of different time period. However, I have noticed that many fire points are much closer together, sometimes only 200m or 300m apart. This spatial distribution seems uneven and unexpected based on the 1 km resolution.
The first picture from FIRMS shows the way the fire point data is being documented. While the second picture shows the actual distance between two points with only 72.33 meters apart. These two points were documented the same year and month.
It seems the distance between each point is not static, probably meaning the 'grid' is changing over time? Is the MODIS grid not static, or are there other factors at play that could cause this discrepancy?



Different grids from different passes (day/night) and different satellites (terra and aqua).

@user2856. The link is fixed now (where you can scroll down at ''What does a fire detection mean on the ground?'' to see the description). I was also wondering if it results from the different satellite but it is not clearly mentioned in the answer of document. Thanks for your comment, and I think it makes sense!

If you open the attribute table of the active fire points, you can see the points that are <1km apart are from different days/times/passes/satellites.
